# Pagination works only on index.php and not archive pages

Tags: pagination

I have a pagination function which i intend using for all pagination on my wordpress blog, but the function doesn't work on archive.php, category-music.php and other archive pages, while it works perfect on my index.php. Here is the code pagination code:

```php
function em_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    
    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if (is_archive()) {
        $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    } else {
        $current_page = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    }
    //$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    
    echo '<div class="em-pagination"><ul class="em-pagination-list">';
    
    if ($total_pages > 1) {
        echo '<li class="em-pagination-prev">';
        previous_posts_link('Previous');
        echo '</li>';
        
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
            if ($i == $current_page) {
                echo '<li class="current"><span>' . $i . '</span></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)) . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        
        echo '<li>...</li>';
        
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($total_pages)) . '">' . $total_pages . '</a></li>';
        
        echo '<li class="em-pagination-next">';
        next_posts_link('Next', $total_pages);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    
    echo '</ul></div>';
}
```

The above function that works correctly on index.php outputs:

```html
<div class="em-pagination"><ul class="em-pagination-list"></ul></div>
```

I also tried running $query->request on within the pagination function on category-music.php, and the output was this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpap_posts.ID FROM wpap_posts LEFT JOIN wpap_term_relationships ON (wpap_posts.ID = wpap_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wpap_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (71,86,87,88,89) ) AND ((wpap_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wpap_posts.post_status = 'publish'))) GROUP BY wpap_posts.ID ORDER BY wpap_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

Note: I have custom post type "song" and "lyrics", so it confuses me that wpap_posts.post_type = 'post'.

Sorry for my English, i am not a native English speaker. Thanks!